# Python 3: Invalid Syntax Error when using * operator in __init__ between pre-defined values defined in-scope

Tags: python-3.x, default-value

I am getting a syntax error when trying to do the following MCVE in Python 3.

```
HEIGHT = 26
WIDTH = 26
OTHERVAR = 5

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, OTHERVAR, HEIGHT*WIDTH):
        print (str(OTHERVAR + HEIGHT*WIDTH))

foo_inst = Foo()
```

Below is the error

```
  File "a.py", line 6
    def __init__(self, OTHERVAR, HEIGHT*WIDTH):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm wondering why the multiplication * operator is invalid syntax in this scenario.

If someone could explain why this is bad syntax and offer a potential workaround, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect `def __init__(self, HEIGHT*WIDTH)` to mean?

Comment: Given that you've tagged the question `[default-value]` apparently you mean something like `def __init__(self, area=HEIGHT*WIDTH)`, and you are missing a *parameter name* like `area`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this aspect of Python syntax. In the full example, other constants defined outside the class are passed in in a similar manner, so my assumption from looking at the full example is that by defining constants and passing the constants as parameters to `__init__`, when instantiating the class, the preset values will be able to be used within the `__init__`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The area example is what I *expected* to be using for default values but the syntax in the question was provided by a professor as part of an assignment.

Comment: Then they maybe made a mistake and you should ask them about that.

Comment: Note: I edited the question to provide a more complete example since the syntax error is specifically for the multiplication aspect.

Comment: `OTHERVAR` is not an error because it would simply mean that `__init__` has a parameter named `OTHERVAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function parameter supposes to be a variable, your HEIGHT*WIDTH produces a value, not a variable.

Are you probably looking for this (default value)?

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> def test(c=a*b):
...     print(c)
... 
>>> test()
2

>>> def test(c=a*b, d):
...     print(c, d)
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

>>> def test(d, c=a*b):
...     print(d, c)
... 
>>> test(10)
(10, 2)
```

And called by named parameters

```
>>> def test(d, c=a*b, e=20):
...     print(d, c, e)
... 
>>> test(10, e=30)
(10, 2, 30)
```

Comment: It's not possible to mix default values and other directly passed parameters since python complains when I define a default value for one parameter but not for the others.

Comment: You just need to reorder the parameters so the ones have default values come last.